# How do I create views and controllers folders in ASP.NET MVC 3 that are specific to a particular role/user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. I want to be able to create an admin panel in the project, so that a set of controllers and views are in an admin folder.

How do I create views and controllers that are specific to a particular role/user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better create a new area, the controllers, views, models, and such folders will be created for you automaticaly.

Right Click on your Project, Add New Area.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest two ways:

1. Create new project
2. Create new area (and maybe tune it to be on a subdomain like admin.mysite.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Areas in MVC. Right click on your Solution and Add Area and then you can have multiple areas in your MVC application. You might need to work on route a bit if those are not configured as per your requirement by default.
Secondly you can have a plugin Architecture as well where you can have multiple projects clubbed together and all will reffer same Global.asax file.

**[Take a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565934/ASP-NET-MVC-plugin-framework)**

Answer (score 0):

for admin panel, the best solution will be to create new areas and assign respective authentications.

As @Antony Teisserie mentioned do create an area name "Admin" so that you can access the admin panel via "your_url.tld/Admin"